# Make Python print whether a integer is positive or negative

Tags: python, integer

Is there any method to add a '+' in front of a integer if the number is positive and a '-' in front of a negative integer.

i know this is fairly simple using if x > y and so forth but it seems a lot of work for little result.

any quick fixes are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `+` format modifier for the `format` function. (Or, equivalently, the `+` for `%`-formatting, but in new code you should probably prefer `str.format`.)

For example:

```py
print('{:+d}'.format(mynumber))
```

Here's an example interactive session showing it in action:

```
>>> '{:+d}'.format(17)
'+17'
>>> '{:+d}'.format(-42)
'-42'
```

For more information see: https://pyformat.info/#number

Comment: @SölviP.: I'm glad I could help! Please feel free to accept this answer if it answered your question.